# Test Class help, have 41% need to make 75%

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

```
public with sharing class generateagreementext {

public string openerfn{get;set;}
public string openerln{get;set;}
public string closerfn{get;set;}
public string closerln{get;set;}
public String leadid {get;set;}
public String underwriter {get;set;}
public String underwriterfn {get;set;}
public String underwriterln {get;set;}
public string ywc{get;set;}
public string feeywc{get;set;}
public string considration_and_funding{get;set;}
public String accman {get;set;}
public String Success_Fee {get;set;}

public Lead lead_data;

public Lead lead;
public Lead leadName;
public List <Lead> leadlist = new List<Lead>();




Public Lead conditionsFromUW{get;set;}

Public static decimal ywcsumval=0.0;
public string formatForCurrency='';
public string ywcsumvalString='0'; 
public Lead authorizedPersonBlock{get;set;}

public generateagreementext()
{}
public generateagreementext(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


       ywcsumval=0.0;
       considration_and_funding='';

       List<String> formatForCurrency = new String[]{'number','###,###,##0'};


       leadid = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');

       authorizedPersonBlock= [SELECT Lead.Authorized_Person_Email_Address__c FROM Lead WHERE id=:leadid];
       conditionsFromUW = [SELECT name,Conditions__c FROM Lead WHERE ID=:leadid];
       system.debug('-----------selected conditons--------'+conditionsFromUW.Conditions__c);
       lead_data = (Lead)controller.getRecord();

       Lead leadres = [SELECT Opener__c,Closer__c,Underwriter__c,Account_Manager__c,Conditions__c,Success_Fee__c FROM Lead where Id=:leadid];

       if(leadres.Opener__c!=null)
        {            
            String[] arropener = leadres.Opener__c.split(' ');
            openerfn=arropener[0].substring(0,1);
            openerln=arropener[1].substring(0,1);
        }
        if(leadres.Closer__c!=null)
        { 
            String[] arrcloser = leadres.Closer__c.split(' ');
            closerfn=arrcloser[0].substring(0,1);
            closerln=arrcloser[1].substring(0,1);
        }
         if(leadres.Underwriter__c!=null)
        { 
            String[] arrunderwriter = leadres.Underwriter__c.split(' ');
                if (arrunderwriter.size()>1){
                    underwriterfn=arrunderwriter[0].substring(0,1);
                    underwriterln=arrunderwriter[1].substring(0,1);
                }
        else{
            underwriterfn=arrunderwriter[0].substring(0,1);
            underwriterln='';
            }
        }
        if(leadres.Account_Manager__c!=null)
           {
            accman =leadres.Account_Manager__c.substring(0,1);
           }
        if(leadres.Success_Fee__c!=null)
           {
            Success_Fee=leadres.Success_Fee__c;

           }

        if(leadres.Conditions__c=='Yes with Conditions') 
          {

              ywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;">';
             for(Condition__c data:[SELECT Condition_Notes__c,Lead_Id__c,Pay_Off_Amount__c FROM Condition__c where Lead_Id__c=:leadid Order By id ASC ])
                  {
                        if(data.Condition_Notes__c!=null)
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+data.Condition_Notes__c+'</li>';
                        }

                        if(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c!=null)
                        {  
                        ywcsumval= ywcsumval + data.Pay_Off_Amount__c;
                        ywcsumvalString= String.format(ywcsumval.format(),formatForCurrency);
                    }
            }  

              //--------Condition Related List Picklist Values----------


               for(Condition__c data:[SELECT  Condition_Type__c,Name_of_Bank__c, Current_Balance__c,New_Balance__c,Pay_Off_Amount__c, Lead_Id__c FROM Condition__c where Lead_Id__c=:leadid Order By id ASC ])
                  {


                      System.debug('-------Conditions Types----'+data.Condition_Type__c);

                        if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Payoff')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Paydown')
                        {
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay down '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Collections')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Bankruptcy')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Judgement')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Authorization')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Liens')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Inquiry Removal')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }

                        else if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Lates')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Pay-off '+ data.Name_of_Bank__c +' account balance '+ 'to $'+ String.format(data.New_Balance__c.format(), formatForCurrency) +'.' +' The amount to pay is $'+String.format(data.Pay_Off_Amount__c.format(), formatForCurrency)+'.</li>';
                        }


                }


                 ywc+='<li>The total amount to pay is $'+ywcsumvalString+'.</li>';

                 for(Condition__c data:[SELECT  Condition_Type__c,Name_of_Bank__c, Current_Balance__c,New_Balance__c,Pay_Off_Amount__c, Lead_Id__c FROM Condition__c where Lead_Id__c=:leadid Order By id ASC ])
                  {

                  if(data.Condition_Type__c=='Entity Creation')
                        {  
                        ywc+='<li>'+'Entity Creation Required.</li>';
                        }

                  }

               for(Bank_Application__c data:[SELECT  Experian1__c,Transunion1__c,equifax1__c FROM Bank_Application__c where Lead_Id__c=:leadid Order By id ASC ])
                  {

                  if(data.Experian1__c=true)
                        {  
        ywc+='<li>'+'Removal of Fraud Alerts with all Credit Bureaus. Please contact:<br/>'+'Equifax 601-502-0198.'    ;                       
            }
                      else 
                         if (data.Equifax1__c=true)
                      {
           ywc+='<li>'+'Removal of Fraud Alerts with all Credit Bureaus. Please contact:<br/>'+' Experian 888-397-3742.';

                      }   
                      else 
                         if (data.Transunion1__c=true)
                      {
            ywc+='<li>'+'Removal of Fraud Alerts with all Credit Bureaus. Please contact:<br/>'+' Transunion 877-322-8228.';

                      }   
                  }



                ywc+='<li>Keep your remaining credit card balances as is or lower.</li>';   
                ywc+='<li>If unable to meet conditions, please contact your Senior Funding Advisor.</li></ul>';        


              System.debug('------------Success Fee 189----------'+leadres.Success_Fee__c );


              if(Success_Fee=='9.99/11.99')  
              {
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>If successful approval is above $35,001, ConsultingFee = 9.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li><li>If successful approval is below $35,000, Consulting Fee = 11.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';              
                  considration_and_funding = ' If Successful approval is above $35,001, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 9.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved. If successful approval is below $35,000, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital an 11.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
              }
              else if(Success_Fee=='9.99')
              {
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 9.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';  
                  considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 9.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';            
              }
            //  if(Success_Fee=='8.5/9.99')  
      //  {
      ///      feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>If successful approval is above $35,001, ConsultingFee = 8.5% of Total Funding Approved.</li><li>If successful approval is below $35,000, Consulting Fee = 9.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';              
      //      considration_and_funding = ' If Successful approval is above $35,001, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 8.5% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved. If successful approval is below $35,000, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital an 9.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
      //  }
              else if(Success_Fee=='11.99')
              {
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 11.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                   considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital an 11.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';             
              }
              else if(Success_Fee=='7.5')
              {
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 7.5% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 7.5% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';                   
              }
            else if(Success_Fee=='8.99'){
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 8.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 8.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
            }
            else if(Success_Fee=='8.5'){
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 8.5% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 8.5% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
            }
            else if(Success_Fee=='7.99'){
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 7.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 7.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
            }
            else if(Success_Fee=='other')
              {

                  Lead leadres1 = [SELECT Success_Fee_Other__c FROM Lead where Id=:leadid];
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = ' + leadres1.Success_Fee_Other__c+ '% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';  
                  considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a ' + leadres1.Success_Fee_Other__c + '% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';            

              }

          }

        else if(leadres.Conditions__c=='No Conditions') {
        ywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;">';
        ywc+='<li>None</li></ul>';

        if(Success_Fee=='9.99/11.99')  
              {
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>If successful approval is above $35,001, ConsultingFee = 9.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li><li>If successful approval is below $35,000, Consulting Fee = 11.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';              
                  considration_and_funding = ' If Successful approval is above $35,001, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 9.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved. If successful approval is below $35,000, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital an 11.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
              }

       /*       else  if(Success_Fee=='8.5/9.99')   
              {
                 feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>If successful approval is above $35,001, ConsultingFee = 8.5% of Total Funding Approved.</li><li>If successful approval is below $35,000, Consulting Fee = 9.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';              
                considration_and_funding = ' If Successful approval is above $35,001, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 8.5% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved. If successful approval is below $35,000, Client agrees to pay Seek Capital an 9.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
             }  */
              else if(Success_Fee=='9.99')
              {
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 9.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';  
                  considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 9.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';            
              }
              else if(Success_Fee=='11.99')
              {
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 11.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                   considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pa'y Seek Capital an 11.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';             
              }
              else if(Success_Fee=='7.5')
              {
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 7.5% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 7.5% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';                   
              }
            else if(Success_Fee=='8.99'){
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 8.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 8.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
            }
            else if(Success_Fee=='8.5'){
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 8.5% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 8.5% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
            }
            else if(Success_Fee=='7.99'){
                feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = 7.99% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>'; 
                 considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a 7.99% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';
            }
              else if(Success_Fee=='other')
              {
                  Lead leadres1 = [SELECT Success_Fee_Other__c FROM Lead where Id=:leadid];
                  feeywc='<ul class="unorlist"  style="font-family:Sans-Serif; text-size:9pt;"><li>Consulting Fee = ' +leadres1.Success_Fee_Other__c + '% of Total Funding Approved.</li></ul>';  
                  considration_and_funding = ' Client agrees to pay Seek Capital a ' +leadres1.Success_Fee_Other__c +'% Consulting Fee of Total Funding Approved.';            

              }

         }


     }         

 }
```

Got this class and need to make 75% for it. For now i have 41% and have this maden.

```
    @istest(seeAllData=TRUE)
public class Test_generateagreementext {

    public Test_generateagreementext()
    {}
    static testmethod void testaddmethod()
    {
        test.startTest();
        generateagreementext g=new generateagreementext();
        g.ywc='abs neko slovce';
        g.accman='b';
        g.closerfn='c';
        g.authorizedPersonBlock=new Lead();
        g.closerln='laskdsd';
        g.conditionsFromUW=new Lead();
        g.formatForCurrency='string neki';
        g.leadid='ID0';
        for (integer i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            g.leadlist[i]=new Lead();
        }
        System.assertEquals(g.ywc, 'bs');
        System.assertEquals(g.accman, 'y');
        System.assertEquals(g.closerfn, 'cggh hh');
        test.stopTest();

    }

    public  static testmethod void generateagreementext(){
      test.startTest();
            Lead ld = new Lead();
            ld.FirstName = 'test';
            ld.LastName = 'Singh';
            ld.Company = 'Singh company';
            ld.email = 'teddst@teesss.com';       
            ld.SSN_Number_Apx_A__c = '123456789742';       
            ld.Recieved_From_Api__c = 'true';
            ld.DNC_Phone__c = '8968474764';
            ld.Opener__c = 'Ryan Kelly';
            ld.Closer__c = 'Richard Cappelli';
            ld.Underwriter__c = 'Roland';
            ld.Account_Manager__c = 'Stephanie';

            ld.Conditions__c = 'No Conditions';

            ld.Success_Fee__c = 'other';
            ld.Conditions_Type_1__c = 'Bankruptcy';
            //ld.Name_of_Bank__c = 'Hdfc';
            ld.Underwriter__c = 'Tony Zacatenco';
            ld.Status='New';
            ld.Merchant_Account__c='13156566646';
            ld.Retirement_Value__c = '321354654654';
            ld.Favorite_Snack__c = 'burger';
            ld.dki__c = 'test lead';
            ld.adg__c = 'googleabc';
            ld.Declared_Bankruptcy__c = 'no';

            ld.ira__c = 'dfs dfg asdf sdf';
            ld.cpn__c = 'dfsdddddd  dd  d d dd d d dd';
            //ld.ID_Received__c = true;
            ld.LeadSource = 'Seek Capital East';
            ld.Industry = 'Agriculture';
            ld.NumberOfEmployees = 15;
            ld.Rating = 'Hot';
            ld.AgreementID__c = '3AAABLblqZhCzveRrdRPoSHeGx8NLSc7oMLCagGEZTpDb652C2ycUu';
            ld.Personal_Credit_Score__c = '720+ (Excellent)';
            ld.Desired_Loan_Amount__c = '12313111';
            ld.Purpose_of_Funds__c = 'Start-Up';
            ld.Funding_Amount_Requested__c = 150000;
            ld.Minimum_Funding_Option__c = 100000.00;
            ld.Client_Industry__c = 'information technology';

            ld.Business_Name__c = 'IT hhh';
            ld.Military_Veteran_Aff__c = 'No';
            ld.Currently_Employed__c = 'Yes';
            ld.Current_Annual_Income__c = 500000.00;
            ld.Current_Annual_Biz_Revenue__c = 2500000.00;
            //ld.Number_of_Business_Credit_Cards_or_Loans__c = '2';
            //  ld.Business_Credit_Card_Lender_1__c = '5687481582144';
            ld.Admin__c = 'Adrienne Liggins';
            ld.Annual_Household_Income__c = 454646464.00;
            ld.Subject__c = 'Awaiting Pre Fund Documents';
            ld.Disposition_Status__c = 'Left Message';
           ld.Disposition_Type__c= 'DL-U- (Limited Credit History)';
            ld.First_Name__c = 'Test';
            ld.Middle_Name_Apendx_A__c = 'abv';
            ld.Last_Name__c = 'sdfsdf';
            ld.Home_Phone_Number__c = '8974561231';

            ld.Email_Address_Apendx_A__c = 'sdfsdf@sfs.ddd';
            ld.Street_Address__c = 'sdf sdf ';
            ld.City__c = 'sdfdffd';
            //ld.State__c = 'sdfddddddffd';
            ld.StateAdd__c='sdfddddddffd';
            ld.Zip__c = '12121';
            ld.County_Appendx_A__c = 'In';
            ld.Time_at_Address_Appendx_A__c = 'asdasd a';
            ld.Equifax__c = true;   
            ld.Transunion__c = true;
            ld.Experian__c = true;

            //ld.team__c = 'UT Team Startup';
            //ld.Team_Agent__c = 'Jarom Oler'; 

            ld.Website='www.google.com';
            ld.MobilePhone='9998887770';
            ld.Fax='8889990000';

            system.debug('---------- before insert --------' );  
            insert ld;
            system.debug('----------- before update --------' );  

            system.debug('-----------selected conditons Lead ID--------'+ld.id);

            String testid =ld.id;
            PageReference pref = Page.GenerateAgreementLocalVF;
            pref.getParameters().put('id', ld.id);
            Test.setCurrentPage(pref);

            System.debug('----------- Lead ID--------'+ld.id);

            System.assertEquals(ld.FirstName , 'test');
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(ld);
            generateagreementext ga = new generateagreementext(sc);

            Lead ld1 = new Lead();

        ld.FirstName = 'test';
            ld1.LastName = 'Singh';
            ld1.Company = 'Singh company';
            ld1.email = 'teddst@teesss.com';       
            ld1.SSN_Number_Apx_A__c = '123456789742';       
            ld1.Recieved_From_Api__c = 'true';
            ld1.DNC_Phone__c = '8968474764';
            ld1.Opener__c = 'Ryan Kelly';
            ld1.Closer__c = 'Richard Cappelli';
            ld1.Underwriter__c = null;
            ld1.Account_Manager__c = null;

            ld1.Conditions__c = 'No Conditions';

            ld1.Success_Fee__c = 'other';
            ld1.Conditions_Type_1__c = 'Bankruptcy';
            //ld.Name_of_Bank__c = 'Hdfc';
            ld1.Underwriter__c = 'Tony Zacatenco';
            ld1.Status='New';
            ld1.Merchant_Account__c='13156566646';
            ld1.Retirement_Value__c = '321354654654';
            ld1.Favorite_Snack__c = 'burger';
            ld1.dki__c = 'test lead';
            ld1.adg__c = 'googleabc';
            ld1.Declared_Bankruptcy__c = 'no';

            ld1.ira__c = 'dfs dfg asdf sdf';
            ld1.cpn__c = 'dfsdddddd  dd  d d dd d d dd';
            //ld.ID_Received__c = true;
            ld1.LeadSource = 'Seek Capital East';
            ld1.Industry = 'Agriculture';
            ld1.NumberOfEmployees = 15;
            ld1.Rating = 'Hot';
            ld1.AgreementID__c = '3AAABLblqZhCzveRrdRPoSHeGx8NLSc7oMLCagGEZTpDb652C2ycUu';
            ld1.Personal_Credit_Score__c = '720+ (Excellent)';
            ld1.Desired_Loan_Amount__c = '12313111';
            ld1.Purpose_of_Funds__c = 'Start-Up';
            ld1.Funding_Amount_Requested__c = 150000;
            ld1.Minimum_Funding_Option__c = 100000.00;
            ld1.Client_Industry__c = 'information technology';

            ld1.Business_Name__c = 'IT hhh';
            ld1.Military_Veteran_Aff__c = 'No';
            ld1.Currently_Employed__c = 'Yes';
            ld1.Current_Annual_Income__c = 500000.00;
            ld1.Current_Annual_Biz_Revenue__c = 2500000.00;

            ld1.Admin__c = 'Adrienne Liggins';
            ld1.Annual_Household_Income__c = 454646464.00;
            ld1.Subject__c = 'Awaiting Pre Fund Documents';
            ld1.Disposition_Status__c = 'Left Message';
           ld1.Disposition_Type__c= 'DL-U- (Limited Credit History)';
            ld1.First_Name__c = 'Test';
            ld1.Middle_Name_Apendx_A__c = 'abv';
            ld1.Last_Name__c = 'sdfsdf';
            ld1.Home_Phone_Number__c = '8974561231';

            ld1.Email_Address_Apendx_A__c = 'sdfsdf@sfs.ddd';
            ld1.Street_Address__c = 'sdf sdf ';
            ld1.City__c = 'sdfdffd';
 ld1.Website='www.google.com';
            ld1.MobilePhone='9998887770';
            ld1.Fax='8889990000';

            String testid1 =ld1.id;
            PageReference pref1 = Page.GenerateAgreementLocalVF;
            pref1.getParameters().put('id', ld1.id);
            Test.setCurrentPage(pref);

            System.debug('----------- Lead ID--------'+ld1.id);

            System.assertEquals(ld1.FirstName , 'test');
            ApexPages.StandardController sc1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(ld1);
            generateagreementext ga1 = new generateagreementext(sc1);

        Bank_Application__c objbA = new Bank_Application__c();
             objbA.Lead_Id__c = ld.id;
             objbA.Approval_Amount__c=120;
            objbA.Equifax1__c = true;   
            objbA.Transunion1__c = true;
            objbA.Experian1__c = true;

             INSERT objbA;
        test.stopTest();   
    } }
```

Comment: Couple of hints: See all Data is bad option, because it may cause unexpected failures in different environments. Writing tests in salesforce may look like next: Open test class in developer console, run that class, open and see which lines are not covered, and add such a test data and method calls to cover uncovered lines. Repeat until it make sense (and 75% coverage) of course

Comment: Honestly, more important than code coverage, you are missing the most important aspect of unit testing: *assertions*. A unit test, this is not. You have simply written a [smoke test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software)).

Comment: HI thank you for your response guys, honestly i did not made this, this was work of some other developers before me, i am not really experienced in testing, so some help would be perfect...

Comment: @IgorStosic - So you essentially want use to write code for you? This is not what SFSE is for. We are here to help you get unstuck in code you have written. If you need someone to write it for you there are plenty of competent developers available for hire.

Comment: @istest(seeAllData=TRUE) - enough for me today :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's set aside, because it's not your code, that assembling HTML in a controller violates the usual best practices for *separation of concerns*.

A common reason for poor test coverage is that the class you're testing makes a lot of decisions and your test data does not represent all possible decisions. You will probably see in dev console that the lines lacking coverage are largely in the `else if` zones of your code.

So what you can do is parcel those decision trees out to a function (whether in the same file or in a helper class). The function takes in the decision criteria and returns the resulting string. Now your unit test can simply test all the possible scenarios of that function - and gives the whole function coverage - without having to generate entire database records that cover all the scenarios.

Comment: When dealing with collection inputs, it is also often easier to separate your code into *filter* and *action* concerns, which are usually co-mingled in one method. The [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) pattern in particular is quite useful for such SOC.